# Error Updating Dynamic Entity When Setting Property Value of Type PickList

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I've added a custom attribute ("custom_contacttype") to the Contact entity.  This attribute is of type picklist which is comprised of seven values.  I'm developing using Advanced Developer Extensions for Microsoft Dynamics CRM against CRM 4.0.  After I set the value for this attribute and call SaveChanges() I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.  I've been battling this one for a while.  What am I doing wrong?  Below is my code:

```
var crm = new CrmDataContext(context.Connection);

var saveContact = crm.GetEntities("contact").Where(p => p.GetPropertyValue<Guid>      ("contactid") == contact.Id.Value).Single();

saveContact.SetPropertyValue("custom_contacttype", 2, typeof(Picklist));

crm.UpdateObject(saveContact);
crm.SaveChanges();
```

Trace Log from CRM Server:
[2011-07-01 16:39:33.7] Process: w3wp |Organization:f827deb3-c6cc-df11-bc07-005056887b79 |Thread:    8 |Category: Platform.Sdk |User: 822138f1-c574-e011-9dca-005056887b79 |Level: Error | PluginStep.Execute
    at PluginStep.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
    at Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
    at MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
    at InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
    at ExternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(String messageName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, PropertyBag fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId)
    at CrmServiceInternal.Update(String namespaceName, BusinessEntityBase entity, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId)
    at CrmService.Update(BusinessEntity entity)
    at RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
    at RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
    at RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
    at LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)
    at WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
    at WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
    at SyncSessionlessHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
    at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
    at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
    at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
    at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
    at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
    at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)

> Web Service Plug-in failed in SdkMessageProcessingStepId: {27DF4121-19BC-DF11-A90E-005056887B79}; EntityName: contact; Stage: 10; MessageName: Update; AssemblyName: AccessCRM.ChangeLogContactData, AccessCRM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a030c130976783ab; ClassName: AccessCRM.ChangeLogContactData; Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at AccessCRM.PluginUtilities.GetStringValueFromProperty(Property p)
>      at AccessCRM.ChangeLogContactData.Execute(IPluginExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PluginStep.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>   .
>   [2011-07-01 16:39:33.7] Process: w3wp |Organization:f827deb3-c6cc-df11-bc07-005056887b79 |Thread:    8 |Category: Platform.Sdk |User: 822138f1-c574-e011-9dca-005056887b79 |Level: Error | PluginExecutionExceptionHandler.Handle
>       at PluginExecutionExceptionHandler.Handle(Stream from, Stream to, Exception exception)
>       at CompositeSoapExtensionExceptionHandler.Handle(Stream to, Stream from, Exception exception)
>       at CrmAuthenticationSoapExtensionBase.ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
>       at SoapMessage.RunExtensions(SoapExtension[] extensions, Boolean throwOnException)
>       at SoapServerProtocol.WriteException(Exception e, Stream outputStream)
>       at WebServiceHandler.WriteException(Exception e)
>       at WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
>       at WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
>       at SyncSessionlessHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
>       at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>       at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>       at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
>       at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)
>       at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>       at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(HttpWorkerRequest wr)
>       at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)
>   CrmSoapExtension detected InvalidPluginExecutionException:
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.InvalidPluginExecutionException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at AccessCRM.PluginUtilities.GetStringValueFromProperty(Property p)
>      at AccessCRM.ChangeLogContactData.Execute(IPluginExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PluginStep.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.PluginStep.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.ExternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(String messageName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, PropertyBag fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.CrmServiceInternal.Update(String namespaceName, BusinessEntityBase entity, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId)
>      at Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Crm2007.CrmService.Update(BusinessEntity entity)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace, the error is actually being thrown in a plugin, not in the code you have pasted above. Look at this line in particular:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
at AccessCRM.PluginUtilities.GetStringValueFromProperty(Property p)
at AccessCRM.ChangeLogContactData.Execute(IPluginExecutionContext context)
```

You'd need to post up the code for that plugin for us to have another look.

Alternatively use [Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt727f1t.aspx) to debug this yourself.

Comment: Thanks.  Very helpful.  I'm not very familiar with plugins.  Found the developer that wrote it.  Working with him on the issue.  Thanks again.

Comment: It's fixed now.  The plugin which is triggered when an update occurs was taking the DynamicEntity, grabbing that picklist property, and looking for the name of the picklist value.  A note was being created to log changes, so it's reasonable that the note display the name of the picklist item instead of the value which is an int.  When setting the property value on the entity I had to pass in an actual Picklist object (name and value poplulated) instead of just an integer value so that the name would be there when the plugin got it.

Comment: Glad it is sorted - you'll find plugins at fault for many a CRM problem.

Comment: glosrob, could you take a look at another question i posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6802124/crmdatacontext-getentities-query-error-0x80040204-invalid-user-auth